# 'MM-YYYY' date format with tinyDatePicker

Tags: date, datepicker

Want to display 'MM-YYYYY' Date format with tinyDatePicker. they have `timeFormatAttribute` attribute to set format but it does not works as expected.

[tiny datepick](https://github.com/PitPik/tinyDatePicker)

I am using this following code to format date but its not changing.

```
  new DatePicker('.datepicker-fca', {
        timeFormatAttribute:'MM-YYYY'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>timeFormatAttribute</kbd> shall be name of attribute. Not format directly ('MM-YYYY' how you using it). See [here](https://github.com/PitPik/tinyDatePicker/blob/3966aeeb069a80502c90223d25176870a4d714a5/demo/indexjq.html#L34).

And how it shall be used you can see [here](https://github.com/PitPik/tinyDatePicker/blob/9c4ccfb89c35dec10bb1778d932a1f91c8663ce8/datePicker.js#L83).

```
            ...
            timeFormat: '',
            timeFormatAttribute:'data-timeformat',
            doAMPM: false,
            ...
```